# Google Apps Script - Cómo obtener permisos para usar openById()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Estoy usando un pequeño programita hecho en **Google Apps Script**.

Lo ejecuto en una planilla de calculo yendo a la sección de "Extensiones", "Apps Script".

La cuestión es que dentro del código del programa, quiero utilizar la función **openById()** para acceder a otra hoja de calculo que no tiene permisos para ser vistos por cualquiera, si no que más bien solo mi usuario de Google está autorizado para hacerlo.

Pero al ejecutar el código, reviso el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Error
> Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Siendo que estoy tratando de abrir mediante esta hoja de calculo mediante la función `openById()`, **¿Cómo puedo conceder permisos para que esa hoja de calculo sea manipulada por cualquier programa de Google Apps Script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesita tu script tener acceso al permiso https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets ese permiso es para que el [script pueda ver, editar, crear y borrar todas las spreadsheets de tu cuenta](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets) no se puede dar scope de un archivo en especifico, se tiene que dar a todo sheets, cuando tratas de correr el script deberia de pedirte autorizar este permiso, ya que es un permiso sensible, tendras una advertencia antes de dar esta autorizacion como esta:
[image: Error: "Google hasn't verified this app"]

Al hacer click en "Advanced" puedes dar la autorizacion de todas formas, y ya podras abrir cualquier sheet por ID, si no aparece el mensaje de autorizacion, podes agregar manualmente el permiso [siguiendo los pasos de este articulo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

Answer (score 2):

No es cierto que para acceder a una determinada hoja tengas que dar permiso a todas las hojas. Eso sería algo absurdo y muy peligroso desde el punto de vista la seguridad.

Puedes asociar tu proyecto de Google Apps Script a un proyecto en Google Cloud Platform, crear allí una Cuenta de Servicio y usar el email de esa cuenta para dar permisos a una o más hojas específicas mediante la opción `Compartir` de las mismas.

Los pasos serían los siguientes:

1. En el proyecto Apps Script, elije la opción **`Configuración del Proyecto`** en el panel izquierdo (es la ruedita de engranaje).
2. Se abrirá una ventana con varias opciones. Fíjate donde dice: **`Proyecto de Google Cloud Platform (GCP)`**. Si tienes un proyecto creado, deberás ver un nùmero al lado de donde dice: **`Número de proyecto`**. Haz click en ese número. Si no tienes un proyecto creado, deberás crearlo en Google Cloud y habilitar la API de Google Sheets.
3. Al hacer click en el número de proyecto irás a la página de Google Cloud Platform. Allí, deberás buscar la opción que dice **`Cuentas de Servicio`** en el panel de la izquierda y hacer click.
4. Una vez en el panel de Cuentas de Servicio, si tienes ya una creada, verás su dirección de email, que es algo como esto: **`nombre-de-proyecto-o-parecido@nombre-de-proyecto-o-parecido.iam.gserviceaccount.com`**. Si no tienes cuentas de servicio, crea una. El hecho es que tienes que copiar su dirección de email. Y usarás esa dirección para dar permiso a la Hoja.
5. Finalmente, abre la Hoja a la que quieres otorgar permisos en Google Sheets. Selecciona **`Compartir`** y en la ventana que se abre, donde dice **`Añadir personas o grupos`** pega la dirección de email del proyecto obtenida en el paso anterior e indica el tipo de acceso que quieres dar a la hoja. Si es sólo para leer sus datos puedes dar el permiso de lector, si quieres modificarla desde el script tendrás que darle permiso de editor como es evidente.

Eso es todo. Y, si quieres dar permiso a varias hojas, simplemente haces lo mismo, abres esas hojas, le das a compartir y agregas la dirección de correo electrónico del proyecto.

Para más detalles sobre las Cuentas de Servicio, [consulta la documentación de Google](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview?hl=es-419).

**PD**:

Puede que otras opciones sean posibles, como usar OAuth por ejemplo. No lo he probado y eso depende del contexto. La ventaja de una Cuenta de Servicio es que permite que el script funcione sin intervención del usuario. Si en tu caso el usuario debe intervenir, puedes plantearte el uso de OAuth, pero en casos en que no deba ser así, lo mejor es una Cuenta de Servicio.